# Protractor scrolling through executeScript not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, protractor, end-to-end

I am testing my Ionic app.

In one page, the button to be clicked is out of the bounds of the window. 
Hence the following code:

```
element.all(by.css('.item.item-complex')).get(9).click();
```

throws the error:

> ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

Hence, I am trying to scroll down the page to make the button visible in page and then try emulating the click on it. I am using the following code:

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0, 200);').then(function() {
    element.all(by.css('.item.item-complex')).get(9).click();
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Vegeta The Prince');
});
```

But the scrolling is not happening with the above code. Please help!

I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I encounter issues like this, I *scroll into view*:

```
var elm = element.all(by.css('.item.item-complex')).get(9);
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm.getWebElement());

elm.click();
```

Comment: how can I reset the scroll back to its original position. For example if I scroll down 3 times and if I want to reset the scroll to the top of the grid, how will I be able to do?

Comment: @VarunMukka usually depends on a use case..but, you can scroll into view of the header row or the first row with data. Please see if it makes sense to create a question if u need help with that. Thanks.

Comment: sure ... I am planning to ask a question

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue using

```
window.scrollTo(x, y)
```

code:

```
var elm = element.all(by.css('.item.item-complex')).get(9);

elm.getLocation()
    .then(function (location) {
        return browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(' + location.x + ', ' + location.y + ');')
    })
    .then(function () {
        return elm.click();
    })
})
```